# Is it correct to say "my ear phones has got tangled in each other"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Is it correct to say "**my ear phones has got tangled in each other**" and "**we need to untangle them**" as shown in the picture?

Comment: The subject **ear phones** is plural. So they **have** got tangled in each other - or merely **entangled** - and yes, you need to untangle them.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entangle

Comment: You are also just say: my earphones are tangled. has got tangled is informal for have become tangled.

Comment: "Earphones" is almost invariably written as a single word with no space.  I would say "my earphones have got tangled up".

Answer (score 5):

> my ear phones has got tangled in each other

“my earphones” is plural (even though you may think of them as a single thing), so you need a plural verb: “have”.

“have got tangled” is apparently correct in BrE; in AmE, you must use “gotten”.

“in each other” should be “with each other”, except we have a special word for that: “together”.

So, the corrected version would be:

> my earphones have gotten tangled together (AmE)
>
> my earphones have got tangled together (BrE)

Your second example is correct:

> we need to untangle them

Comment: _Have got tangled_  is perfectly correct in British English! You could also say _we need to disentangle them._

Comment: _Gotten_ is regarded as archaic in British English. See https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/06/irregular-verbs-gotten-fit-knit.html

Comment: String A has got tangled in string B and String B has got tangled in string A, so they have got tangled in each other? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @Tom If I go to the movie with you, and you go with me, it is technically correct to say we went “with each other”, but any fluent speaker would say we went “together”.

Comment: Things that are tangled together, like Tom's earphones, are not tangled *in* each other.  They are either tangled together as Stephen suggest or they are tangled *with* each other.  For something to become tangled *in* something else it usually should be contained within or covered by that thing.  A fish becomes tangled *in* a net, a fly in a spider's web, and gum can become entangled in your hair.  My shoe laces, however, become tangled *with* each other.

Comment: @KateBunting Edited for that difference between AmE and BrE. Thanks.